# createBlockBlobFromStream() is overriding existing content instead of appending

Tags: node.js, angular, express, azure-blob-storage

We work with very large files so we devide them into chunk of 20mb then call the upload function to upload them to blob storage.I am calling upload() in node js where I found that I am missing something while upload. Only 20mb is getting uploaded each time , I doubt  nodejs is overriding the content rather than appending the stream.

can somebody help to fix it?

```
const chunkSize = Number(request.headers["x-content-length"]);
const userrole = request.headers["x-userrole"];
const pathname = request.headers["x-pathname"];

var form = new multiparty.Form();
form.parse(request, function (err, fields, files) {
if (files && files["payload"] && files["payload"].length > 0) {
var fileContent = fs.readFileSync(files["payload"][0].path);
// log.error('fields',fields['Content-Type'])
fs.unlink(files["payload"][0].path, function (err) {
if (err) {
log.error("Error in unlink payload:" + err);
}
});
var size = fileContent.length;
if (size !== chunkSize) {
sendBadRequest(response, "Chunk uploading was not completed");
return;
}
//converting chunk[buffers] to readable stream
const stream = Readable.from(fileContent);
var options = {
contentSettings: {
contentType: fields['Content-Type']
}
}
blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream(containerName, pathname, stream, size, options, error => {
});
```

Headers:

```
X-id: 6023f6f53601233c080b1369
X-Chunk-Id: 38
X-Content-Id: 43bfdbf4ddd1d7b5cd787dc212be8691d8dd147017a2344cb0851978b2d983c075c26c6082fd27a5147742b030856b0d71549e4d208d1c3c9d94f957e7ed1c92
X-pathname: 6023f6ae3601233c080b1365/spe10_lgr311_2021-02-10_09-08-37/output/800mb.inc

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryqodrlQNFytNS9wAc
X-Content-Name: 800mb.inc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're using `createBlockBlobFromStream` which will overwrite the contents of a blob. This method is used to create a blob in a single request (i.e. complete blob data is passed as input). From the documentation [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/bb8550b4dca615b54eb12b21c5a5eae0e35548c7/lib/services/blob/blobservice.core.js#L3123):

> Uploads a block blob from a stream. If the blob already exists on the
> service, it will be overwritten. To avoid overwriting and instead
> throw an error if the blob exists, please pass in an accessConditions
> parameter in the options object.

In your case, you're uploading chunks of the data. What you would need to do is use [`createBlockFromStream`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/bb8550b4dca615b54eb12b21c5a5eae0e35548c7/lib/services/blob/blobservice.core.js#L3261) method for each chunk that you're uploading.

Once all chunks are uploaded, you would need to call [`commitBlocks`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/bb8550b4dca615b54eb12b21c5a5eae0e35548c7/lib/services/blob/blobservice.core.js#L3497) method to create the blob.

**UPDATE**

> How can we generate the blockId?

A block id is simply a string. Key thing to remember is that when you're calling `createBlockFromStream`, the length of block id of each block you're sending must be the same. You can't use `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11...` for example. You will have to use something like `01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11...` so that they're of same length. You can use GUID for that purpose. Also, the maximum length of the block id is 50 characters.

> should it be unique for all?

Yes. For a blob, the block ids must be unique otherwise it will overwrite the content of a previous block uploaded with the same id.

> can u show the example code so that i can try similar way to
> implement?

Please take a look [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/bb8550b4dca615b54eb12b21c5a5eae0e35548c7/test/services/blob/blobservice-uploaddownload-tests.js).

Basically the idea is very simple: On your client side, you're chunking the file and sending each chunk separately. What you will do is apart from sending that data, you will also send a block id string. You will also need to keep that block id on your client side. You will repeat the same process for all the chunks of your file.

Once all chunks are uploaded successfully, you will make one more request to your server and send the list of all the block ids. Your server at that time will call `commitBlocks` to create the blob.

Please note that the order of block ids in your last request is important. Azure Storage Service will use this information to stitch the blob together.

Comment: what do you mean by one more request? isnt it in same API? just check if eof to call commitblocks?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you elaborate your comment. Commit block list is a separate operation than Put block operation. You use Commit block list to signal Azure Storage Service to create the blob by combining all blocks. You may find this link useful to understand it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list.

Comment: actually I am bit confused on when to call commitblock(), is it in the same API that am using for createblockfromstream() or seperate API needs to be called?

Comment: It would depend. There are two possible cases: 1) You upload the entire file from your client to your server and then do a chunked upload from your server to blob storage using `createblockfromstream()`. In this case, it will be the part of the same API. 2) From your client you upload the chunks to your server and you call `createblockfromstream()` to upload those chunks to blob storage. In this case, it will be a separate API call that will just call `commitBlocks` to commit the blocks you have uploaded in the previous operations.

Comment: can we call commitblock after each blockcreating? or we need to call it only once and after all the blocks are created?